# Making hash crawlable with #! and surviving the change

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor, hashbang

I'm trying to make my site crawlable by changing the # to #!. The page works OK when clicking on the link, but I cannot manage to fix the script for calling the hash directly from the URL.

This is what I have

HEAD

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs a").click(function() {

        var page = this.hash.substr(2);

        $.get(page+".php", function(gotHtml) {
            $("#content").html(gotHtml)
        });
    });

    (location.hash) ? $("a[href="+location.hash+"]").click() : $("#tabs a:first").click()

});
```

BODY

```
< ul id="tabs">

< li>< a href="#!foo" >foo</a>< /li>

< li>< a href="#!foo2" >foo2</a>< /li>

< li>< a href="#!foo3" >foo3</a>< /li>

< /ul>
```

When I click on foo, content loads ok, but if I call my site with www.foo.com/#!foo, it doesn't load the content.

Can anyone guide me?

Comment: FYI - That's called a hashbang.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in your error console you'll see that it's throwing the following exception:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href=#!foo2]

In order to fix this, you can change your JavaScript ever so slightly.

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs a").click(function() {

        var page = this.hash.substr(2);

        $.get(page+".php", function(gotHtml) {
            $("#content").html(gotHtml)
        });
    });

    (location.hash) ? $("a[href='"+location.hash+"']").click() : $("#tabs a:first").click()

});
```

Notice I just stuck single quotes around your href portion of your selector.

On a related note, I would recommend that if you're going to do hash-bangs (they are a headache) that you make the `href` attribute the actual URL value that you're going to. In the JavaScript do the switch over to a hash-bang. The reason for this is that users with JavaScript disabled will not be able to use your site.  Your click function will change ever so slightly to set the hash, load the page, and disable the default click behavior.

*Update for question:* On the related note, I meant if the `href="#!foo"` change that href to actually be `href="foo.php"`.  If a user does not have JavaScript enabled they can go to foo.php and see the page.  If the user does have JavaScript place the hashbang in the URL and do what you did previously.  You can do this manually; however, libraries like [jQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) can really make this trivial.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! It works flawless now! Could you please elaborate when you say " make the href attribute the actual URL value that you're going to". I don't get it... maybe an example?

I'm sorry I'm a total noob, I know!

Thanks a lot again!